# ANSI standard add/drop multiple columns

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Is there an ANSI standard syntax for add/drop multiple columns?  something like

```
alter table MyTable 
add column1 int,
add column2 int
```

(this doesnt work in sql server)

Comment: To my knowledge, there's not even an ANSI standard for adding/dropping a _single_ column (ie ALTER TABLE is not a part of the standard)

Comment: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt Search for <alter table statement>

Comment: So the ANSI syntax is "alter table MyTable add column1 int;" However, "alter table MyTable add (column1 int, column2 int);" might also work in your DB

Comment: @Multisync the reason why i asked for ANSI standard is because I want cross DBMS support, and the syntax you just posted doesnt work

Comment: I posted 2 ways - the first one is ANSI, the second one works in Oracle (I wrote "might work"). Anyway, I doubt it's possible to write one universal DDL for several DB, people usually write one DDL for each DB. For example, you may experience problems with datatypes.

Comment: @Multisync yea..looks like standard only supports one add not multiple

Comment: There is no standard and I would be very surprised if you can find a statement to add a *single* column that works across "all" DBMS equally well. You should rather try to use some kind of templating engine to generate different SQL for different DBMS.

Comment: *‘the reason why i asked for ANSI standard is because I want cross DBMS support’* – I hope you realise that there being an ANSI standard for something in SQL doesn't automatically give you cross-DBMS support for it.

Comment: @AndriyM it gives support to almost all major DBMS and that's good enough